# gradle can't build android project due out of memory

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I'm getting this error when i try to build my project on android studio

```
Out of memory: Java heap space.
Please assign more memory to Gradle in the project's gradle.properties file.
For example, the following line, in the gradle.properties file, sets the maximum Java heap size to 1,024 MB:
<em>org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m</em>
```

my `grandle.properties` is:

```
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

4GB isn't enough? why?????

the project isn't super huge... the whole `src` folder has 4MB

and my only dependencies are: retrofit, gson, and the support library

The only thing i notice weird is:
This project is a fork from a github project, initially the project had all its images as PNG at different sizes... so the whole project was over 10MB i used an online tool to convert this png into svg->xml drawable for android...

I've checked and tested and those drawables are fine

But during compilation, android studio creates a folder `build\generated\res\pngs` and there tons of pngs are copied... even if there isn't any at the project

what might be happening?

============update===============

the error always happen during `packageDebugResources` how can i check which resource was on task?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove fork options :

> tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
>       options.fork = true }